# Getting HTML headings to be dynamically output by Razor

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I am creating a page in Razor and I am trying to dynamically output headings depending on how deep the node is.

So the top level node is a h1, second level h2 etc...

The bit I am struggling is getting razor to dynamically output the headings. Half of it seems to be working but the closing tag will not output.

This is the razor:

```
<h@{@parts} id="#@item.Id">@sectionString@level @item.Name </h@{@parts} >
```

Which outputs the following HTML:

```
<h4 id="#1073">4.1.1 Get a baseline </h@{@parts} >
```

If I remove the forward slash it works, but then i end up with `<h3><h3>` rather than `<h3></h3>`.

I have also tried:

```
<h@{@parts} id="#@item.Id">@sectionString@level @item.Name </h@parts >

<h@{@parts} id="#@item.Id">@sectionString@level @item.Name </h@{parts} >
```

If I can't get this to work I guess I will have to resort to a very long if statement which I would rather avoid. I think the slash needs escaping somehow? Thank-you.

Comment: What does variable @parts contain?

Comment: It is a number from `var parts = sectionString.Split('.').Count()+1;` I have just worked it out and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out!

```
<h@{@parts} id="#@item.Id">@sectionString@level @item.Name @Html.Raw("</h")@parts@Html.Raw(">")
```

I just had to escape the code, it doesn't look tidy but it works.

Edit: The comments below show a much better way of doing this. Thanks for those!

Comment: Perhaps something like this `@Html.Raw(String.Format("<h{0} id='#{1}'>{2}{3} {4}</h{5}>", parts, item.Id, sectionString, level, item.Name, parts));` would look a bit cleaner?

Comment: To add up on @Max's comment - if you are using C#6, you can make it even tidier with string interpolation: `Html.Raw($"<h{parts} id='#{item.Id}'>{sectionString}{level} {item.Name}</h{parts}>");`

Answer (score 2):

Better to make a helper:

```
@Heading(1, (sectionString + level + item.Name), item.Id)
@Heading(2, "Sub heading")
@Heading(3, "Lesser heading", "anyId")

@helper Heading(int headingLevel, string title, string id = null)
{
    @if (id != null)
    {
        @Html.Raw(string.Format(@"<h{0} id=""{1}""",  headingLevel, Html.Encode(id)))
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("<h{0}>",  headingLevel))
    }
    @title
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("</h{0}>", headingLevel))
}
```